Python WSGI/websocket server in Apache: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
On an Ubuntu 22.04 environment, I'm trying to access to my webcam on a web page using Python using Opencv library (called cv2).
The code works well when I execute it on my local interpreter. But when I include it in a localhost web page using a websocket and cv2, both modules can't be imported :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' 
(of course, the library is installed in my Python environment). If I replace cv2 by the numpy module, the import works well.
Here is an example of code using Apache with WSGI.
Virtual Host Configuration (/etc/apache2/site-availables/cam.loc.conf)  :
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName cam.loc
    ServerAlias www.cam.loc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Apache_with_Python/cam/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Apache_with_Python/cam/opencv_with_wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess cam.loc processes=3 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup cam.loc    
    <Directory /var/www/Apache_with_Python/cam>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://cam.loc:8085

    ErrorLog /var/www/Apache_avec_Python/cam/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/Apache_avec_Python/cam/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Then, the /var/www/Apache_with_Python/cam/opencv_with_wsgi.py page contains the following :
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import numpy
import asyncio

import websockets
import cv2

(...)

def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == "/":
        return default(start_response, environ['PATH_INFO'])

import cv2 causes an 500 error from Apache, and same for websocket.
Importing thoses 2 modules on the local interpreter instead works fine.
Any idea of what I should check ?

Python version : 3.10
opencv-python : 4.9.0.80

Thank you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

[mre] required.

you say it's an import issue? then it's an environment issue. not enough detail provided to give an answer. can't even guess what you might have done.
